# Stopping fraud by looking for patterns in data 

Tags: sql, security, audit

What applications are recommended for SQL Server auditing and, more specifically, fraud investigations?

I need a tool that allows an end user to correlate data values to find fraud patterns. This tool must allow tuning as needed to reduce false positives.

It's also important that it be fairly intuitive. Ideally, once in place it would allow an end user unfamiliar with SQL to interface with it directly and customize using a GUI interface.

Suggestions?

Comment: "Fraud patterns" is a very broad term, and would be totally different depending on the type of data- is this banking, credit, lending, legal?  You're talking about advanced data analysis, in any case.

Comment: For example, lets say a table contains names, addresses, city, state, zip, and CC# -- all in different columns.  I want to be able to audit that table for duplicate last names without the same CC# or duplicate CC# associated with different names.

Comment: ...or, from a SQL security perspective, I want to watch for instances of malicious code within a database without installing SQL management studio and writing queries.  I want a tool that I can search for instances of "<script>" or "http:" for example.

Comment: Let me try to clarify further: If you have a BestCardEver credit card and use it to by a plasma TV in FL to be shipped to NY, then 10 minutes later buy a couch in CA and have it shipped to a different address in KS, I want an application that I can watch for that pattern and flag it as potential fraud.  In this case, I know what i'm looking for programatically (if CC# in transaction1 = CC# in transaction2 and shipping address != equal, then flag).  

Credit card company's do it all the time.  What do they use?

Comment: @Chad,  they use data mining,  i suspect "Verified by visa" does something like this.  There isn't a simple programmatic way to solve this extremely complex problem.

Comment: As The Rook says, this is a data mining/machine learning problem. Research and development of data mining applied to these problems is currently very active, but it is by no means a solved problem. I can point you to a few general purpose data mining tools, but I don't know of any shrink-wrapped easy-to-use GUI application available for this purpose.

Comment: General purpose tools would be a start.  Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Weka (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a pretty intuitive and popular open source app in Java. It has a companion book that is a good introduction to data mining. Rapidminer(http://www.rapidminer.com) is another popular open source Java app that has a very nice GUI and is more complete than Weka - in fact it can use all of Weka's algorithms as plugins. It has a 'premium' version with more capabilities. These two are the only ones I have used, but as I said the area is very active now so there are a lot being done, some of which may suit you better.

Comment: Another thing: data mining techniques can get incredibly sophisticated, but a few elementary techniques introduced in any data mining or pattern recognition textbook may get you a long way. Especially if you have lots of data. The KISS principle applies.

Answer (score 1):

It varies from simple business rules - user of type X aren't allowed to change discounts, no more than N uses of a coupon.

Through to some very clever Bayesian inference engine stuff that finds customer X's surname is the arabic translation of Mr Y's name who signed for him as a mortgage guarantee and they claim different home addresses but in the same zip code.    This stuff gets very '6figure' pricey

Comment: what's an example '6figure' application?

Answer (score 0):

Data-mining is used by law enforcement and credit card companies to stop criminals.  There are patterns in large data sets that can reveal a greater motive.  The more data the law enforcement has,  the better they can track down the criminal(s).

You want to gather as much data as you can about a crime that may happen.  This means you want to run a Network Intrusion Detection System (NIDS) on the Database's network.  Snort is a very good NIDS and its free and open source. You wan to provide as much evidence of a crime to law enforcement and the FBI will **LOVE** your snort logs.  I say *when* because its only a matter of time.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Sadly though this doesn't answer my question.  I'm also not talking about layer three intrusion detection/prevention nor am I talking about something that would involve law enforcement.

Comment: I think you are talking about data-mining, without a doubt you'll have to build this from scratch.